# How to export multi line string to single line text

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, multilinestring

I have a text file "c:\zz.txt" of which an extract is as follows:

```
#N ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF
#D UT-ABSAAG
#P 20190215    393.83    393.83   0.00

#N ABSA BALANCED FUND
#D UT-ABSABA
#P 20190215    432.28    432.28   0.00

#N COMMUNITY GILT
#D UT-COM-G
#P 20190215    151.21    151.21   8.59
```

I would like to export this to a .TXT file with following format:

```
UT_Name,UT_Code,Date,Value1,Value2,Vol
ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF,UT-ABSAAG,20190215,393.83,393.83,0
ABSA BALANCED FUND,UT-ABSABA,20190215,432.28,432.28,0
COMMUNITY GILT,UT-COM-G,20190215,151.21,151.21,8.59
```

My code below

```
clear-Host
get-content -raw "c:\zz.txt" | % { $_ -replace '(#N)',"`r`n"} |% { $_ -replace '(#D|#P)',','}|Set-Content ZZ1.txt
```

Output:

```
ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF, UT-ABSAAG, 20190215    393.83    393.83   0.00
ABSA BALANCED FUND, UT-ABSABA, 20190215    432.28    432.28   0.00
COMMUNITY GILT, UT-COM-G, 20190215    151.21    151.21   8.59
```

Issue:
The problem turns out to be that dataset "#P" in original dataset is fixed length which means I can't simply replace all whitespaces, with commas as this will also affect field names "#N" and "#D" above which I dont want to affect.

How do I selectively replace white spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this uses named capture groups to get the items and then exports it to a CSV file.

```
# fake reading in a raw text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Raw
$InStuff = @'
#N ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF
#D UT-ABSAAG
#P 20190215    393.83    393.83   0.00

#N ABSA BALANCED FUND
#D UT-ABSABA
#P 20190215    432.28    432.28   0.00

#N COMMUNITY GILT
#D UT-COM-G
#P 20190215    151.21    151.21   8.59
'@

# split into blocks, trim unwanted whitespace, filter out the blank block
$SplitInStuff = ($InStuff -split '#N').Trim().Where({$_})

$Results = foreach ($SIS_Item in $SplitInStuff)
    {
    $Null = $SIS_Item -match '(?sm)(?<UT_Name>^.+$).*#D (?<UT_Code>.+).*#P (?<Date>\d+)\s+(?<Value1>[0-9.]+)\s+(?<Value2>[0-9.]+)\s+(?<Vol>[0-9.]+)'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        # the ".Trim()" was needed to remove leftover EOL/NewLine/space chars
        UT_Name = $Matches.UT_Name.Trim()
        UT_Code = $Matches.UT_Code.Trim()
        Date = $Matches.Date.Trim()
        Value1 = $Matches.Value1.Trim()
        Value2 = $Matches.Value2.Trim()
        Vol = $Matches.Vol.Trim()
        }
    }

$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\milkywaypizza_ProductInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

content of the CSV file ...

```
"UT_Name","UT_Code","Date","Value1","Value2","Vol"
"ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF","UT-ABSAAG","20190215","393.83","393.83","0.00"
"ABSA BALANCED FUND","UT-ABSABA","20190215","432.28","432.28","0.00"
"COMMUNITY GILT","UT-COM-G","20190215","151.21","151.21","8.59"
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method :

```
$Data = @'
#N ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF
#D UT-ABSAAG
#P 20190215    393.83    393.83   0.00

#N ABSA BALANCED FUND
#D UT-ABSABA
#P 20190215    432.28    432.28   0.00

#N COMMUNITY GILT
#D UT-COM-G
#P 2019021    151.21    151.21   8.59
'@

#template for learn schema
$template=@'
#N {Vol_ABSA_ALL_ROUNDER_FoF*:ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF}
#D UT-{UT_Name:ABSAAG}
#P {Date:20190215}    {Value1:393.83}    {Value2:393.83}   {Vol:0.00}

#N {Vol_ABSA_ALL_ROUNDER_FoF*:ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF 2}
#D UT-{UT_Name:ABSAAG2}
#P {Date:20190216}    {Value1:393.83}    {Value2:393.83}   {Vol:0.00}
'@

$Data | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: I think it's important to add the following disclaimer whenever [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) is used: It provides separator-based parsing as well as heuristics-based parsing based on templates containing example values. The separator-based parsing applies automatic type conversions you cannot control, and the template language is poorly documented, with the exact behavior hard to predict - it's best to avoid this cmdlet altogether. Also note that it's not available in PowerShell _Core_.

Answer (score 1):

## How do I selectively replace runs of multiple whitespace characters?

E.g., by only selecting multiple spaces with a quantifier `-replace " {2,}",','`

The following script based on your one liner:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\28\SO_55387785.ps1
$FileIn = '.\zz.txt'
$FileOut= '.\zz1.txt'

 Set-Content $FileOut -Value "UT_Name,UT_Code,Date,Value1,Value2,Vol"
(Get-Content $FileIn -raw) -replace "(`r?`n)?#N " -replace "`r?`n(#D|#P) | {2,}",',' |
 Add-Content $FileOut
```

yields this output:

```
> Get-Content .\ZZ1.txt
UT_Name,UT_Code,Date,Value1,Value2,Vol
ABSA ALL ROUNDER FoF,UT-ABSAAG,20190215,393.83,393.83,0.00
ABSA BALANCED FUND,UT-ABSABA,20190215,432.28,432.28,0.00
COMMUNITY GILT,UT-COM-G,20190215,151.21,151.21,8.59
```